# .htaccess redirection fails when slash in index.php/

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

am having the below code in my .htaccess file,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /home
RewriteRule ^home$ / [L,R=301]
```

it successfully redirects when `www.domainname.com/index.php` to `www.domainname.com`.

But it fails to redirect when URL given like `www.domainname.com/index.php/`
(a URL with slash after index.php)

Comment: What happens when you request a URL with the trailing slash? Do you get a 404 or does the page still load?

Comment: that page loads, but i need to redirect it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way by making trailing slash optional in both the rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /+index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /home [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: You have to place this rule as very first rule in your htaccess.